# Scrape links from many Google searches in Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, urllib, scrape

I want to scrape the 1st link that shows up on a Google search for 23000 searches and append them to the dataframe I am using. This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file.py", line 26, in <module>
website = showsome(company)
File "file.py", line 18, in showsome
hits = data['results']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
import json
import urllib
import pandas as pd

def showsome(searchfor):
    query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
    search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    search_results = search_response.read()
    results = json.loads(search_results)
    data = results['responseData']
    hits = data['results']
    d = hits[0]['visibleUrl']
    return d

company_names = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")

websites = []
for company in company_names["Company"]:
    website = showsome(company)
    websites.append(website)
websites = pd.DataFrame(websites, columns=["Website"])

result = pd.concat([company_names,websites], axis=1, join='inner')
result.to_csv("export_file.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

(I changed the name of the input and output files for privacy reasons)

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the json data has not been well processed and then results does not contain 'responseData'.

Comment: Catch the exception and print out some of the variables when the error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try just answer why this exception is raised-

I see google detects you and post a formatted nice response i.e.

```
{u'responseData': None, u'responseDetails': u'Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors', u'responseStatus': 403}
```

Which is the then assigned to `results` by below expression.

```
results = json.loads(search_results)
```

So `data = results['responseData']` is equals to `None` and when you run `hits = data['results']` - `data['results']` raises error since `data` is `None` and it does not have `results` attribute-

I tried to use `random` module ( just a simple try) to simulate real through some wait- ( **But i strongly oppose using this if you do not have permission from google** BTW i used `time.sleep(random.choice((1,3,3,2,4,1,0)))` as below.

```
import json,random,time
import urllib
import pandas as pd

def showsome(searchfor):
    query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
    search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    search_results = search_response.read()
    results = json.loads(search_results)
    data = results['responseData']
    hits = data['results']
    d = hits[0]['visibleUrl']
    return d

company_names = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")

websites = []
for company in company_names["Company"]:
    website = showsome(company)
    websites.append(website)
    time.sleep(random.choice((1,3,3,2,4,1,0)))
    print website
websites = pd.DataFrame(websites, columns=["Website"])

result = pd.concat([company_names,websites], axis=1, join='inner')
result.to_csv("export_file.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

It generates csv that contains-

```
Company,Website
American Axle,www.aam.com
American Broadcasting Company,en.wikipedia.org
American Eagle Outfitters,ae.com
American Electric Power,www.aep.com
American Express,www.americanexpress.com
American Family Insurance,www.amfam.com
American Financial Group,www.afginc.com
American Greetings,www.americangreetings.com
```